# Is there a difference between the black and silver Nikon 50mm f/1.8 E series lenses?

Tags: lens, nikon

The Nikon 50mm f/1.8 E-series has 2 versions: black (1979-1981) and silver (1981-1985)

Is there any difference between these 2 versions, apart from the color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later version has a chrome ring, but the differences are cosmetic - both are inexpensive, mostly plastic lenses, and optics are the same: [6 elements in 5 groups](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/emfgfg20/eserieslenses/htmls/283550mm.htm).  They [removed](http://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/50mmnikkor/index5.htm) the chrome ring again when they released the AI-S version.

> ...the second update of the Series E 50mm f/1.8s finally being improved
>   with some cosmetic in a more shiny finishes, aided with the reversal
>   of decision of an aluminum lens mounting ring...